# Date error when inserting output value from TSQL Merge command into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, merge, output

I cannot seem to insert a datetime value into a table using output parameters.
I get the following error.

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My merge statement is below. If I run the SQL without the INTO clause, I get no errors.  The output, as shown on the screen, is included below.

I have tried every variation of CAST and Convert that I can see and I still get the same error.  I can successfully insert records into the table using regular insert commands with the date value being supplied by Getdate() or using quoted text in the format of the dates shown in the ascii table below.

The new_createdate and old_createdate columns are dattime in my changelog table.

I am at a loss for why the dates returned from inserted and deleted don't seem to want to go into a table without this error.

```
MERGE jobtbl PJP
USING myjobtbl CPI
ON PJP.jobnum = CPI.jobnum
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET PJP.customer = CPI.customer,
PJP.createdate = CPI.createdate,
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
(jobnum,
customer,
createdate)
VALUES
(cpi.jobnum,
cpi.customer,
cpi.createdate)
OUTPUT
$ACTION action,
inserted.jobnum jobnumcol,
inserted.createdate new_createdate,
deleted.createdate old_createdate,
inserted.customer new_customer,
deleted.customer old_customer,
INTO [dbo].[changeLog];



+-------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+--------+
|action |jobnum| new_createdate     |  old_createdate    |new_cust |old_cust|
+-------+-----+---------------------+--------------------+---------+--------+
|UPDATE |169853| 2016-06-17 13:34:00| 2016-06-17 13:34:00| CHIENE  |CHIENE  |
|UPDATE |169743| 2016-05-20 14:07:00| 2016-05-20 14:07:00| DOZJOS  |DOZJOS  |
+-------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Does the structure of your `changeLog` table match the column order in `OUTPUT`?  Can you post the table DDL?

Comment: I believe so.  Does column order matter even if I am explicitly naming the columns in the output clause?  Does every column in the changelog table have to be included in the inserted and deleted statements?

Comment: I believe so, as you are just giving them an alias.  Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` script of your changeLog table?

Comment: I checked and I did have a column out of order.  That seems to be the issue.  I am using output and merge for the first time so I've made a few mistakes along the way. I'm a bit confused as to why order matters in the column list as each column is explicitly named such as inserted.jobnum, deleted.jobnum etc.  I understood these to be coming from some sort of memory or temporary table in SQL Server.  Not sure if I can mark your answer as the correct one in a comment but that is the right answer. Column order matters.

Comment: Submitted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your table column order to match the insert.